# What does add_theme_support('custom-header-uploads'); feature do?

Tags: add-theme-support

Whilst adding features to the `functions.php` file, I came across the following:

`add_theme_support('custom-header-uploads');`

What exactly does this do?  I removed the entry, in the `functions.php` but saw no difference to the website.  I initially thought it had something to do with the ability to upload header images but that is down to `add_theme_support('custom-header');`

I cannot see any meaningful information, when performing a search, across Codex.  Is this some kind of depreciated feature or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably does nothing. I cannot find any reference in the [developer resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=custom-header-uploads) or the [theme handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/?s=custom-header-uploads).

Also doing a quick search through WP source code shows this is only used in *wp-includes/theme.php*, and even there only in the parts about adding/removing theme support.

Comment: I struggled to find anything on the feature.  I assume you have never found any use for it and have worked with WordPress, without any problems?

Comment: @Craig Exactly, never heard of it before and been doing fine ;) As I said, there is no mention in the developer resources (Codex is old, developer.wordpress.org is new) and none in the core code

Comment: Ahhhh well.  I shall not worry myself too much over it then.  I was wondering  why there was a lot of duplicate content with Codex and developer.wordpress.org.  Atleast I learnt something from this question.  Thank you for your time. :-)